# enumerating every computably infinitary sentence

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, computability

Given a computable $L$-structure $\mathscr{A}$, can you enumerate every computably infinitary sentence of $L \cup \{a\}_{a \in A}$ in an effective way?

Comment: Do you really mean all the c.i. sentences and not just (say) the $\Sigma_1$ ones? The former is extremely complicated, essentially at the level of [Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O).

Comment: yeah I meant them all, ok so it is hard to enumerate? I know for any $\alpha<\omega_1^{CK}$ we can enumerate all the computable $\Sigma_\alpha$ sentences, but what about all of the computable infinitary sentences?

Comment: Nope, you can't do that in any good way. (See also "$\Sigma^1_1$-bounding," which basically says you can never easily separate the well-founded-but-arbitrarily-large objects from the ill-founded ones; here it's telling us that any simple process that grabs all the c.i. formulas will also grab some garbage "formulas.")